# Establishing HTTP2 connection with AVS (Python -- requests library)

Tags: http, python-requests, alexa-voice-service

I'm following [amazon's guide](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/managing-an-http-2-connection) in creating a python application that can access Alexa. I have obtained my access/refresh tokens, and am trying to open a HTTP2 connection with AVS.

Since I'm doing this in python, I've utilized the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to manage all my HTTP connections stuff. However, I can't seem to get past the first step of opening a connection with AVS. I *think* the problem is simply my syntax in my request, as I'm not sure how certain elements of the get request are supposed to be represented in the HTTP call. Specifically,

> To establish a downchannel stream your client must make a GET request to /{{API version}}/directives within 10 seconds of opening the connection with AVS. The request should look like this:

```
1 :method = GET
2 :scheme = https
3 :path = /{{API version}}/directives
4 authorization = Bearer {{YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}}
```

To start, the part of the instructions where it states

> ...within 10 seconds of opening the connection with AVS

Would that be a separate call from the GET request to `/API version/directives`? If so, what would that look like?

Then, for the actual call to `/API version/directives`, my code looks like this (Python):

```
def establishDownstream():
  url = "https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com/v20160207/directives"
  foo = "Bearer " + ACCESS_KEY
  payload = {"authorization" : foo}
  g = requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

My reasoning is that since it's a `requests.get()` call, the `:method = GET` is taken care of, since the url starts with `https://`, the `:scheme = https` is taken care of, and the url itself takes care of the path (again, correct me if I'm wrong). Then I simply need to pass my access key as value to `authorization`, which I do through `params`. However, this is not leading to any success (the specific error message is `requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)`).

I really don't know what's going on here. All the guides I found online regarding HTTP request protocols structure their requests in a block form, not through a python library, so I have no examples to work off of.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think requests supports http 2

Comment: I was under the impression that HTTP/2 was primarily an "under the hood" update so to speak, and the most of the protocols such as GET and POST were the same...? Also, `requests` worked fine when I used it to grab the access token, also from Amazon.

Comment: Have you searched for the error message? See e.g. https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3006

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you are correct, it doesn't. There is  a lib hyper  that does but it is very much in the alpha stages http://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: The docs actually encourage hyper for use with python https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations