# AVS V2 Establishing HTTP2 Connection

Tags: python, python-requests, http2, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to create an HTTP/2 connection using Python, Requests, and the Hyper HTTP20Adapter (for HTTP/2 support) to AVS (Version 20160207 of the API). I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952758/establishing-http2-connection-with-avs-python-requests-library), and determined that my main problem was coming from Requests not supporting HTTP/2 -- I believe I have fixed that with my use of the Hyper module.

[Amazon's instructions](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/managing-an-http-2-connection) say to `GET` a down channel stream, then on that same connection, `POST` a `SynchronizeState` event.

This is my attempt at sending the two requests:

```
downstream = requests.Session()
downstream.mount('https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com', HTTP20Adapter())
qheader = {"authorization": "Bearer " + ACCESS_KEY}
sheader = {"authorization": "Bearer " + ACCESS_KEY, "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=metadata","Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
spayload = {"context": [],"event": {"header":{"namespace":"System","name":"SynchronizeState","messageId":"SyncState",},"payload": {}}}

q = downstream.get("https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com/v20160207/directives", headers=qheader, stream=True)

s = downstream.post("https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com/v20160207/events", headers=sheader, data=json.dumps(spayload)
```

However, I'm consistently getting this error message:

```
INVALID_REQUEST_EXCEPTION, description: No multipart body found in the payload.
```

This persists even if I take out the `data=json.dumps(spayload)` line in the `post` request and replace it with `json = spayload`.

I have two main questions:

1) I'm not sure that I'm making both requests on "the same connection" as instructed. Am I (I thought that `requests.Session()` took care of that, but...)? If not, how would I do that?

2) How do I resolve the "No multipart body found in payload" message? I sent their [example SynchronizeState event](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/reference/system) exactly, and it specifically said to include an empty payload.

Thanks in advance for the help! Anything is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1) sorry, I don't know - I had problems using the adapter - my requests were not terminating, so I switched to using the asyncio protocol-based flow shown in the [hyper server example](http://python-hyper.org/projects/h2/en/stable/asyncio-example.html) (it's not too bad to convert that to a client use-case)

2) I resolved this by making sure I ended the stream when sending the headers in the initial GET and after sending the data in the POST. (`self._conn.send_data(stream_id, sync_post_data, end_stream=True)`